# Finding the Eclipse Project file location

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I have an android project running in Eclipse IDE. Lets say it is 'ABC Project'. Some of my collieges have made number of copies of this project, so the project files can be seen in desktop, C://, D:// and even in eclipse work space. Now I don't know project in which location I am running because they have deleted and imported the project folder to eclipse using this copies and they can't remember whether they selected the option 'make a copy to the workspace'.. How can I get this location? I tried to right click on the project and see any option is there but no. Manually finding it using java code (getAbsolutePath()) will return no good, it will return the path in the phone.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try right click on project ->Properties->Resources ? You will be able to see the path there.

Comment: @AdityaKamath: Perfect! It shows the location as workspace, so this is the location of the project right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try right click on project ->Properties->Resources ? You will be able to see the Project path there.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on project and click on Resources.

In that it shows the location where it is .

Find it out dude :)

Answer (score 2):

Properties -> Resource -> Linked Resources -> PROJECT_LOC

Answer (score 1):

Use Alt+Enter on the project Name in Eclipse to see the complete path of the project directory where it resides.

[image]